# Jupyter notebook: No module named 'notebook.base'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I'm trying to create a simple HTML version of a notebook without the code.

```
jupyter nbconvert "HFB data dashboard.ipynb" --to html --no-input
```

But it returns:

```
line 18, in <module>
    from notebook.base.handlers import APIHandler, IPythonHandler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.base'
```

I'm using notebook version 7.1

Comment: `nbconvert` needs to be [installed](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).  Are you sure you have it in the current python / conda env?

Comment: @darked89 Yes I have.

Comment: the fairly recent thread listing few putative solutions: [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76893872/731351)